# Why don't USB-C hubs have a full USB-C port with PD and data?

Tags: usb, usb-c

Every USB-C hub I have seen only comes with a USB-C port that either only supports PD or only supports data.  My laptop has USB-C ports which support both PD and data (for example, when sending a video output upstream but charging downstream at the same time).  Ideally, I'd like a hub with a USB-C port that has this same functionality, but I can only find ones that support one or the other - never both.  Is this a design limitation with the USB-C controllers, or something else?  Is this a function only offered by Thunderbolt?

Comment: Taking a guess, but could be either design restrictions for cost or lack of power. There are chargers on the market that have 2 USB-C PD ports, so that's not an impossible engineering design. But it may be possible that the USB-C port going to the hub can't output more than x watts without burning up.

Comment: Well, my USB-C docking station has a USB-C port that can be either.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Which one do you have?

Comment: no-name generic USB-C docking station with 2 USB-C ports, gigabit ethernet, HDMI

Comment: Also are you sure it's just USB-C?  Not Thunderbolt?